# Markdown - code as link in GitHub readme

Tags: github, markdown

I wanted to create inline span of code that links to other page.

I want to use

```
`MongoCollection`
```

and

```
[MongoCollection](#http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php)
```

together to make a link on a code element.

I tried

```
[`MongoCollection`](#http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php)
```

and

```
`[MongoCollection](#http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php)`
```

Both didn't work.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to add a link within a code block (using the markdown ``` or `)?

Comment: This question is better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it's not dealing with coding but how the Markdown works) or direct to GitHub:Support

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain a bit more about what you mean by inline span of code?  This works in Github and links the MongoCollection link to the Mongo Collection php manual page.

`[MongoCollection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php)`

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I edited question. Hope now you understand what I want to achieve.